# How to add convention to specific property in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper and I want to add Convention for specific property name, such as ABC_DEF -> ABCDEF. I know how to add convention for all properties names. How to add only for specific property?
Thanks.

For all property names:

```
AddMemberConfiguration().AddName<ReplaceName>(_ => _.AddReplace("Ä", "A").AddReplace("í", "i"));
```

**EDIT:**

For example class with properties:

```
        public class Test
        {
            public int ABC_PROP1 { get; set; }
            public int ABC_PROP2 { get; set; }
            public int ABC_PROP3 { get; set; }
            public int CDE_PROP4 { get; set; }
            public int EFG_PROP5 { get; set; }
        }
```

And I want to replace "_" only in properties starts with ABC. But without MapForm. Is it possible use convention?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MapFrom for a specific property name. It lets you redirect from one property to another.

Comment: But this is only for one concrete property. I want to map group such as. Dev_Prop1, Dev_Prop2, ... to DevProp1, DevProp2. I wan't write MapFrom for each property. I have a lot of these properties. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need to update your question, you asked how to add only for a specific property. MapFrom is for a specific property. The member configurations are for groups of members.

Comment: Or maybe post a few more types? Is it only a group of types you're trying to affect? Or just one single type? And is it underscores that's the problem?